Play stream source with sound by using MediaPlayer in UWP
I use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement. I try to play a stream from m3u8 playlist, but the stream plays without sound.
You can download playlist with channels which helps to reproduce issue Google Drive Click
I initialize source of Media Element like below:
MediaElement.Source = ViewModelLocator.IptvViewModel.SelectedChannel?.Url;
SelectedChannel.Url is link for channels. I use channel Viju + Sport. In vlc player this channel plays with sound.
To reproduce you can create an empty UWP project, add a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement to the page and set Source to link of the Viju + Sport channel.

Do you mean set the "Source="http://stream02.vnet.am/AutoPlus/mono.m3u8"? I get the error "unsupported video type or invalid file path".  Could you please share your detailed steps to help me understand the problem?

@JunjieZhu-MSFT, Try to set Source via code like this: MediaElement.Source = new Uri("http://stream02.vnet.am/AutoPlus/mono.m3u8", UriKind.Absolute)

Can you use other tools or other APIs to access this link to see if there is sound? I used your code and still got the same error "unsupported video type or invalid file path".  you could try adding AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" in the xaml to see if there is same error on the control.
